# How to hide a javascript html script tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to hide a javascript script block from desktop and be able to show it on mobile only.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  javascript code
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify - javascript script blog?

Comment: I think he means block

Comment: How about an `if` statement instead?

Comment: By "hide" do you mean you want the server to not send the tag to begin with if the `User-Agent` header indicates a mobile browser, or you want the javascript to not execute on a device if it detects (somehow) that it's running on one?

Answer (score 1):

Well, its not 100% clear what you mean, but I assume you want to execute some JS code only when you are on a mobile device!

There have two ways to accomplish this.

1. You can try to analyze the HTTP request on the server and inspect the User-Agent header to find out if it's a mobile browser. Depending on that you can generate the script block or not. What server side enviroment are you using?
2. Or you wrap the JS code in an `if`, and execute it depending on the User-Agent, which you analyze on the client. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery) for more information on how to do that.

Comment: You also ask a question have way through the answer.

Comment: @j08691 Did I say `my bad`? Damn. Sorry, man... My bad.

Comment: @ParthianShot - Gaaaaah!

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Fixed. Now it's no longer painfully obvious that the answerer's first language is "txt msg".

Answer (score 0):

## 2 solutions:

- 1 - make the check **server-side** http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ then serve the js code you want.
- 2 - make the check **client-side** http://modernizr.com/ then load the script you want using the [yep/nop](http://yepnopejs.com/) pattern

Answer (score 0):

You can make this with check User Agent, so if you want hide javascript block from desktop browser you can use PHP, like this :

```
<?php 
if( strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'Android') ||
   strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'webOS') || 
   strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPhone') || 
   strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPod') 
): ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    javascript code
</script>
<php endif; ?>
```

Or you can use javascript inside your tag if you want run your code only for mobile device :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) ||
    navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) ||
    navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || 
    navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
){ 
    javascript code
}    
</script>
```